# Social authentication and publishing library for iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, facebook-social-plugins

Is there an open source or commercial library that makes authentication and publishing to multiple social networks easier? We are developing an iPhone app and it will be used by Facebook, Twitter and Linkedin users and in the future Google will be added to the list of providers so we want to save ourselves from developing for each of these networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ShareKit is what you're looking for:

http://getsharekit.com/

The website doesn't mention any LinkedIn support yet, but it looks like someone has submitted a pull request here:

https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/pull/271

Comment: I saw that but does it support login with the provider's own login pages? We want our users to sign in with facebook's or twitter's own login page. Otherwise the app doesn't seem trustful.

Comment: Yes, the Twitter and Facebook services both use a webview to log the user in through the provider's own login pages. For example, the Facebook authentication looks like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1395097/Screenshots/11.png

Comment: Ok that's what we want. Thank you Mark!